# Uploadify: Getting object or parent id

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I have a page where file upload inputs will be customizable via a backend, so my call to uploadify is on a class, like this:

```
$('.uploadify_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader'  : '../js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script'    : '../js/uploadify/uploadify.php',
            'cancelImg' : '../js/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'checkScript' : '../js/uploadify/check.php',
            'folder'    : '../img/uploads/temp/<?= $upload_temp_folder ?>/',
            'auto'      : true,
            'multi'     : false,
            'buttonText': 'Upload image',
            onComplete: function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                $('#file_name').text(fileObj.name);
            }
        });
```

The html looks like:

```
<div class="image_preview" id="preview_<?= $field['field_name_in_channel_data'] ?>">
                                    <input type="file" class="uploadify_upload" id="upload_<?= $field['field_name_in_channel_data'] ?>" name="upload_<?= $field['field_name_in_channel_data'] ?>"/>
                                </div>
```

I want to be able to obtain the div id (`preview__..`) or input id(`upload_...`) inside my uploadify function. This way, I can let the backend know for which field the upload was, in order to appropriately write in the DB later. I tried

```
'onSelect'    : function(event,data) {
                    var div_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
                    alert(div_id);

                },
```

among others but without success.. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
'onSelect'    : function(event,ID,fileObj) {
    var elem_id = $(event.target).attr("id"); //here you get the id of the object.
    $("#"+elem_id).uploadifySettings('scriptData',{'formID':elem_id})
},
```

From [Uploadify: Passing a form's ID as a parameter with scriptData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524712/uploadify-passing-a-forms-id-as-a-parameter-with-scriptdata)